# Los Angeles Lakers info?

Tags: basketball, history

- When did the Lakers come into existence?
- When did they win their first championship?
- When did they become the Lakers?

Answer (score 5):

For your question about the Los Angeles Lakers I was able to do some initial research however I was curious to know if you meant where the name "Lakers" came from or if you meant when did they move to Los Angeles becoming the team that we know today when you asked "when the Lakers became the Lakers"

I will answer both question just to be on the safe side.

The Los Angeles Lakers came into existence in 1947 in their first season they were known as the Minneapolis Lakers because they were located near Mississippi River hence the name "Lakers". The Lakers moved to Los Angeles before the 1960-61 season.

As for the question of when the Lakers won their "first" championship it is a complicated answer that I will do my best to explain.

The Minneapolis Lakers won their first "NBL" National Basketball League championship in 1947, however their first official "NBA" National Basketball Association championship came in 1949. However the Los Angeles Lakers earned their first championship in 1972.

I think that [this official Los Angeles Lakers website](http://www.nba.com/lakers/history/lakers_history_new.html#2) can help you with any further Los Angeles Lakers information that you might need.

Answer (score 2):

> When did the Lakers come into existence? When did they become the lakers?

The Lakers, then known as the Minnesota Lakers, inaugural season was the 1947-48 season as part of the National Basketball League (NBL).

The Minnesota Lakers moved to Los Angeles before the 1960-61 season.

> When did they win their first championship?

Their only championship as part of the NBL was in 1948.

Their only championship as part of the Basketball Association of America (BAA) was in 1949.

On August 3, 1949, The BAA merged with the NBL to create the National Basketball Association (NBA). Their first championship as part of the NBA was in 1950.

The Lakers have also won championships during the 1952, 1953, 1954, 1972, 1980, 1982, 1985, 1987, 1988, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2009, 2010 seasons.

[SOURCE](http://www.nba.com/lakers/history/lakers_history_new.html)